# Адрес отправки вопросов в codenet

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, форум

После щелчка на `Создать новую тему` в http://forum.codenet.ru/add-question получил следующее окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выяснилось содержимое страницы попало в комментарий

```html
<!--

<form action="/404.php" method="post" id="answer_form">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8">


<div class="form-group">
 <span id="select_form_tr_show">
  <label for="forums_filters_select_select">Раздел:</label>
  <span id="forums_filters_select">
   <select name="id_forum" id="forums_filters_select_select" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Необходимо выбрать 1 из 35</option>
    <option value="-1">--------------------</option><option value="32">ASP.NET</option><option value="8">Borland C++ Builder</option><option value="30">C/C++/C# - общие вопросы</option><option value="6">Delphi &amp; Kylix</option><option value="40">FAQ - Список наиболее часто задаваемых вопросов</option><option value="41">Haskell / Erlang / OCaml и т.д</option><option value="20">HTML</option><option value="26">Java</option><option value="28">Microsoft .NET Framework</option><option value="7">Microsoft Visual C++</option><option value="34">NET SDK (Fusion, Unmanaged API...)</option><option value="9">Pascal</option><option value="42">Python / Ruby / Groovy и пр.</option><option value="39">SEO</option><option value="17">SQL сервера</option><option value="13">Visual Basic</option><option value="19">Web программирование</option><option value="23">Win32 API</option><option value="33">Windows Forms</option><option value="31">Базы данных</option><option value="16">Базы данных и язык SQL</option><option value="10">Графика</option><option value="36">Железо</option><option value="21">Компьютерная безопасность</option><option value="12">Низкоуровневое программирование</option><option value="11">Общие вопросы программирования</option><option value="14">Операционные системы</option><option value="43">Программирование под Android, iOS, HP WebOS.</option><option value="25">Программирование под Linux/Unix</option><option value="27">Студентам</option><option value="-1">--------------------</option><option value="37">Гаджеты</option><option value="4">Обсуждение сайта www.codenet.ru</option><option value="22">Общалка :)</option><option value="24">Работа</option><option value="38">Фриланс</option>   </select>
   <div id="forums_filter_description" style="display:none;margin-top:10px;" class="alert alert-info"></div>
  </span>
  <p class="help-block" id="forums_filters_link">показать: <a tabIndex="-1" href="#" id="forums_all">все разделы</a>, <a tabIndex="-1" href="#" id="forums_forum">разделы для общения</a>, <a href="#" tabIndex="-1" id="forums_qa">разделы для вопросов</a></p>
 </span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label id="question_or_theme" for="caq-create_title">Тема</label>
 <input type="text" name="title" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="caq-create_title" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="input_tags">Теги:</label>
 <input type="hidden" name="tags" value="" autocomplete="off" id="input_tags_hidden" /><ul id="input_tags"></ul>
 <p class="help-block">через запятую, старайтесь выбирать теги из списка</p>
</div>

</div></div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Логин:</label>
     <input type="text" name="login" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Пароль:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="panel-footer">
    <p class="text-muted"><a target="_blank" class="text-danger" href="/reg">Регистрация</a> &mdash; <a target="_blank" href="/restore-password/">Забыли пароль</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <div style="float:right;padding:10px;"><a style="color:red;" href="http://forum.codenet.ru/q72176/" target="_blank">Как форматировать текст!</a></div>

 <div class="ei">
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Жирный" class="bold"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Подчеркнутый" class="underline"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Курсивный" class="italic"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Перечеркнутый" class="strike"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Ненумерованный список" class="ul"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Нумерованный список" class="ol"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Цитата" class="quote"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Вставить картинку" class="image"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Вставить ссылку" class="link"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Прикрепить файлы" class="attachment"></a>
  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" title="Вставить форматированный код" class="code"></a>
  <span id="toolbar_progress"></span>
 </div>

 <textarea class="form-control" autocomplete="off" rows="10" id="answer_textarea" name="question"></textarea>

 <input type="hidden" name="images" id="answer_images" value="" autocomplete="off" />
 <input type="hidden" name="files" id="answer_files" value="" autocomplete="off" />

<div style="padding:15px 0 0 0;float:left;">
<div style="float:left;">
Кросспост в:
</div>
<div title="Необходимо настроить свзять между аккаунтами." style="opacity:0.2;float:left;"><label for="crosspost_facebook"><input style="display:block;float:left;margin:2px 5px 0 20px;" type="checkbox" name="crosspost_facebook" id="crosspost_facebook" disabled="disabled"  /><img src="http://i.codenet.ru/caq/img/social/facebook.png"" style="float:left; display:block;width:18px;height:18px;margin:0 5px 0 0;" />Facebook</label></div><div title="Необходимо настроить свзять между аккаунтами." style="opacity:0.2;float:left;"><label for="crosspost_twitter"><input style="display:block;float:left;margin:2px 5px 0 20px;" type="checkbox" name="crosspost_twitter" id="crosspost_twitter" disabled="disabled"  /><img src="http://i.codenet.ru/caq/img/social/twitter.png"" style="float:left; display:block;width:18px;height:18px;margin:0 5px 0 0;" />Twitter</label></div><div style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 40px;">
 <a href="/my-social/" target="_blank" style="font-size:11px;">(настроить)</a>
</div>

</div>

 <div id="answer_button"><span></span>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Добавить вопрос" class="btn btn-success" />
 </div>

</form>


<div id="answer_preview_title" style="clear:both;color:#888;display:none;padding:10px;">Предварительный просмотр сообщения: <span style="color:#ddd;font-size:10px;"></span></div>

<div id="answer_preview" style="overflow:hidden;"></div>

-->
```

После расскомментирования и после ввода и отправки данных, из-за

```
<form action="/404.php" method="post" id="answer_form">
```

получил окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите на какой адрес я должен бы был перейти (если бы в `action` стояло бы правильное значение).  Введите в адресной строке forum.codenet.ru/add-question , заполните в ней данные и отправьте, а затем посмотрите куда перейдет веб-браузер - на какую страницу , и пришлите адрес этой страницы (именно она меня и интересует).

Comment: Нам-то откуда знать?

Comment: @u_mulder ну введите в адресной строке http://forum.codenet.ru/add-question , заполните в ней данные и отправьте, а затем посмотрите куда перейдет веб-браузер - на какую страницу , и пришилте адрес этой страницы (именно она меня и интересует). Или можете на http://forum.codenet.ru/add-question открыть Дополнительные инструменты -> Инструменты разработчика и на ней найти вышеуказанный блок кода (и посмотреть чему равно `action`)

Comment: То есть разработчики сайта случайно закомментировали форму?

Comment: С учетом того что даты последних ответов на этом форуме датируются 2019-м годом - форум помер и задавать новые вопросы на нем - бессмысленно. Поэтому форма и закоментирована.

Comment: @u_mulder нет форма закомментирована из-за моих действий (сам не понял как так произошло). Но в любом случае напишите пожалуйста куда переходит браузер после отправки данных.

Comment: Форма закомментирована разработчиками сайта. Если ты разработчик сайта - то у меня для тебя плохие новости.

Comment: @u_mulder по боку. Главное что я хочу - это получить адрес страницы, куда переходит браузер. Напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ладно, здесь до здравого смысла не достучаться.

Comment: Извините меня за мою непонятливость (дубовость) - проявите понимание я новичок. Правильно ли я понял, что в результате открытия forum.codenet.ru/add-question у вас тоже содержимое не грузится?

Comment: Не грузится, у всех не грузится. __Форум помер__.